# sql query to select credit cards about to expire

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have credits card table that has `month` and `year` fields which store values like `02` and `2013`. I am new to sql and not sure where to start. How do I select only those records which expire few days before credit card are expired in order to send email to customers that their credit cards are about to expire.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT * FROM credit_cards WHERE (what here?)
```

Alternatively, I can select all records from table and from php code check dates for cards that are about to expire eg 5 days before but again I am not sure what php code should be written for.

Many thanks for the help

---

## Update

I have come up with this query:

```
SELECT * from credit_cards WHERE (concat(year,'-', month, '-01') < CURDATE())
```

Is that correct way to get it ? Although I am not receiving sql error.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM credit_cards 
WHERE month = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND year = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

This will give you the cards expiring in current month.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM credit_cards 
WHERE month = MONTH(CURDATE())
AND year = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: `year = YEAR = YEAR`?